# What happens if I send ETH to ICN (erc20 token) address when trying to use shapeshift on parity?

Tags: parity, recovery, shapeshift

The ETH get stuck on the address and when I contact Shapeshift, whey said: Unfortunately we do not own this address.

Is it possible that they or the parity have a bug. The address that I used was offered to me inside the parity web interface.

Comment: What is the destination address you have used? Usually token contracts will reject ether being sent after their crowdsale.

Comment: this is the transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdef1991619c8f1b2027116e8a569f9653d0067f03ac2107611b4b8b0d32f76c9.  i didnt use this for crowdsale. I just wanted to change ETH to ICN but by mistake send ETH to the address for ICN

Comment: Shapeshift generates an identifier "Order ID" for each transaction if you have it that may help them determine if there was an error and reinburse your ether. But otherwise it is unlikely they can do something if they do not have the private key for that address.

Comment: is it possible to get the order ID somewhere inside the parity. I did all the actions inside the parity (they have integrated shapeshift)

Comment: I've used Shapeshift from my browser, you can try searching the history, but I don't think they are saved. You can ask the parity guys if they save it.